why does a carbon-halogen bond make that carbon less acidic (in this case)?
A question I came across treats this molecule with KOtBu which forms an anion...

The correct anion is:

An incorrect anion is:

I don't understand why this is - I'd have thought that the C of the C-Cl bond would be the most acidic (as in the incorrect answer) as the Cl atom would stabilise the conjugate base better inductively (compared to when the Cl is more bonds away).
edit: I'm now thinking it has something to do with the resonance stabilisation? So perhaps this isn't true in most cases but is here because of the delocalisation onto the oxygen?

I would say it has to do with the base. Potassium tert-butoxide is quite bulky and it's easier to remove a proton from the side without the chlorine atom. Plus, chlorine is also quite electronegative and draws the negative charge towards itself, leading to less effective delocalization.

Anion 2 may well be more acidic and stable than anion 1. I am afraid that the selection of anion 1 as "more stable" than anion 2 is because anion 1 undergoes the Ramberg-Bäcklund reaction (RBR)[2], which does not mean that anion 1 is more stable. Chlorosulfoxides 3 and 4 have been isolated and characterized.[1] They are two of four possible racemic stereoisomers. Given the inductive effect of chlorine and the $\ce{C2}$-H on the exo-face of the ring system, it is likely that this is the kinetic site of deprotonation and possibly the more stable anion.
Treatment of 3 and 4 with t-BuOK/DMSO at room temperature afforded bicyclo[2.2.0]hex-2-ene (6) via, what is generally believe to be, the intermediate 5 with lose of sulfur monoxide. [Incidently, bicycle 6 was converted to [5]-ladderane 7.]

Paquette, et al.,[3] observed that chlorosulfone 9 in another aprotic solvent, tetrahydrofuran (THF) at 0 oC, underwent the ring contraction to form tricyclic triene 11. However, when chlorosulfone 9 was heated in refluxing  dioxane (bp. 101 oC) in the presence of $\ce{NaOD/D2O}$, only deuterium exchange occurred. If this experiment were conducted at lower temperature, exchange would be expected to be slower and provide an opportunity to assess (NMR) which protons are exchanging faster. Alternatively, one might be able to do the study on chlorosuloxides 3 and 4 directly. The exchange rate in 3 and 4 is anticipated to be slower than with 11 and 12 if one considers as models the pKa's of dimethyl sulfoxide (DMSO; pKa=~33) and dimethyl sulfone (pKa=~23).


Mercer, J. A. M., et alia, J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2016, 138, 15845.
L. A. Paquette, The Ramberg-Bäcklund Reaction, Organic Reactions On Line. (with access)
Paquette, L. A., Philips, J. C., and Wingard Jr., R. E., J.Am. Chem. Soc., 1971, 93, 4516.


Ah i see - i should have made clear that the question didn't actually say that anion 1 was more stable.
So just to make sure: anion 1 (my top anion) is probably the (kinetic and thermodynamic?) product of deprotonation, but it's just that anion 2 (my bottom anion) goes on to form the bicycle and the ladderane etc.
